# QT : QTranslate is not working with QObject subclass

Tags: c++, qt, qobject, qtranslate, qtranslator

QTranslate is working fine with tr and QObject::tr but when I try to create a subclass of QObject its generating the correct ts file but unable to read it back.

```
class Reporting : public QObject { };

Reporting::tr("I Am Reporting.");
```

please help Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a correct QObject. A designating macro and vtable are required, also you might want to provide ownership mechanism.

```
class Reporting : public QObject { 
       Q_OBJECT

       Reporting (/*whatever*/ QObject* parent = 0 )
       : QObject (parent) /*whatever*/ 
       { /*whatever*/ }

       ~Reporting ()
};
```

in C++ file

```
//virtual destructor
Reporting ::~Reporting () {}
```